# Clashing imports between Python modules

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging, pythonpath

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── main.py
├── package
│   ├── module.py
│   └── utils.py
└── utils.py
```

Inside `package`, I have (lots of) code in which all imports are relative to `package`, e.g. `package/module.py` contains `import utils`, and it expects to import `package/utils.py` (not `utils.py`).

All the code outside `package` expects imports to be relative to the root directory `.`.

This is causing an issue for me because if `main.py` contains `import package.module` and I have `PYTHONPATH=.`, then `package/module.py` ends up importing `utils.py` instead of the desired `package/utils.py` (since it contains `import utils`).

How do I resolve this without having to rename scripts? I would like to install the code in `package` in a way so that I can import it in `main.py` without its imports clashing with my other files.

What I tried: I added a minimal `setup.py` file inside `package` and ran `pip install -e .` but that didn't resolve the issue.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: just a suggestion - name your packages and modules more descriptively - using the same filename for different files is confusing as f**ck :)

Comment: Thanks! I agree with descriptive naming, but files such as `utils.py` tend to lie in various folders containing utilities for that folder. Nonetheless, the code in `package/` is third-party code, the naming of which is of course not in my control... I am hoping there's a solution to this scenario where you can "package away" third-party code in `package/` without having to rename or edit code in it to avoid naming clashes...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a relative import for Submodules?

So that in general you would use

```
import utils  # Import ./utils.py
import .utils # Import relative ./<eg. package>/utils.py
```

That would cause Scripts under 'package' to always import their local utils.py

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I am hoping for a solution where I don't have to rename or edit any of the code inside `package/`, because there's a lot of it (it's third-party code). I'm wondering whether I can instead "package away" `package/` so it doesn't interact/clash with my code.

Comment: Can you think of how I can turn the folder inside `package/` into a package that doesn't interact with other code? I've recently been wondering if `setuptools.setup`'s `package_dir` and `packages` arguments might be worth playing with to achieve this?